# How to show from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to take  first row  information from my DB  and define to my solution array 
(please look picture)
[I have 3 columns  (title, slogan and description)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClrT6.png)

And I want to define  "my title", "my slogan",  "my description" to my solution array

```
    const solution = [
     {
       title: // it should be "my title",
       slogan: // it should be "my slogan",
       description: // it should be "my description"
     }
   ];
```

Comment: are you able to make connection with MongoDB server using mongoose,  also share the code you have tried

Comment: Yes I have connection, and I have ejs form where I can submit and add new information in my DB

Comment: mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const postsSchema = {
  title: String,
  slogan: String,
  description: String
};
const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postsSchema);

Comment: app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("solution");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    slogan: req.body.slogan,
    description: req.body.description
      });
      post.save(function(err){
        if (!err){
            res.redirect("/");
        }
      });
    });

Comment: app.get("/api/solutions", (req, res) => {
 const solution = [
     {
       title: // it should be "my title",
       slogan: // it should be "my slogan",
       description: // it should be "my description"
     }
   ];});

Comment: do you know how find works?

Comment: No, can you help me with solution?

Comment: man, just search tutorial for CURD operations in mongoose

Comment: https://kedarsedai.github.io/blog/2020/03/11/Build-RestAPIs/ refer to this @vrto95

Comment: thank you it was helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show your data as formatted text, not as an image. [This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. Additionally, please move your code from comments (unformatted, very difficult to read) into your original question (again, formatted properly). This will help considerably.